AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) in android not working
I am using the above to force my application to be in dark mode
theme:
<style name="Base.Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar" />

<item name="obColorSingleToneWhite">@color/default_single_tone_white</item>

and I have two color files one in values and one in values-night.
I use this in the fragment onCreate():
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
I tried before and after the super.onCreate()and in the xml:
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="@color/default_single_tone_white"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

The background is rendered in the color of the default not the night
I also used the setDefaultNightMode function in the main activity onCreate() 
I tried also adding a theme in the values-night, copy pasting everything in the default theme, still not working
What is missing?
